# Google Apps Script Error Message: document.getElementById not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am new to JavaScript and CSS but I'm trying to create a script for a Google doc that creates an image that toggles between the image and a black box when the viewer clicks on it. I'm using js, html, and css. When I run the script, I get an error message that says:

> "TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function."

I've searched around and I can't figure out why I'm getting this particular error message. What am I missing?

Script:

```
function toggleImg(){
  var document = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML').getContent();
    var imageToggle = document.getElementById("toggleImage");
  imageToggle.classList.toggle("toggle-on");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="toggleImage" class="image-container toggle-on" onClick="toggleImg(this)"  >

<?!= include('CSScode.html'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

.image-container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-container.toggle-on {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/vChK6pTy3vN3KbYZ7UU7k3-1200-80.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
;}

.image-container img{
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}

</style>
```

Comment: You're mixing server side scripts and client side scripts. Server doesn't have document. It should be inside client html <script> tags

Comment: I would advise you read https://coder-coder.com/learn-web-development/ @Elliott before going forward with developing a web app. It would help you understand the difference between front and back and other important topics.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be beneficial for you if you took a look at [client to server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) official guide in GAS and get you covered in terms of what can and cannot be done